# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes when I connect external monitor through USB-C

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

When I connect an external monitor through USB-C my system freezes completely and the fans start spinning full speed and I can't do anything. It was working before but now all of the sudden it has stopped working. I used to be able to connect 2 extra external monitors (through HDMI and USB-C)

*P.S. When I connect the monitor and then turn on the computer then it hangs at the splash loading screen.*

Here is my setup:

```
Laptop - Lenovo Legion 5 (1 HDMI port and 1 USB-C port)
Intel i5 10th gen
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 (with NVIDIA proprietary driver installed)
```

What I have tried so far but did not help

`apt update && apt upgrade`

Comment: What's dmesg says ? (`/var/log/dmesg*`). Simpler way is to run `dmesg -wT > ~/file.log` before plugging in ; you'll get the last logs in `file.log` after reboot.  Also, a more complete setup could be helpful (drivers, etc) > `$ inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS` with inxi package

Comment: I'm coming too late to edit my comment, you can also explore full journal logs with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` (-1 for previous boot, -2 for the one before, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Choose nvidia-driver-510 and disable Wayland and running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

has solved my issue